# Hibernate Validator, custom ResourceBundleLocator and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to override default ResourceBundleLocator in hibernate validation 4.1. So far it works perfectly, but the only examples of its usage include java code to instantiate ValidationFactory.

When using a web application with spring hibernate validation is automatically configured (only the suitable hibernate validation *.jar file should exist and it is automatically used). How can i substitute ResourceBundleLocator in that scenario? I do not see any way of specyfing my custom ResourceBundleLocator in any properties or applicationContext.xml file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The magic method that does the required job is [LocalValidatorFactoryBean#setValidationMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html#setValidationMessageSource(org.springframework.context.MessageSource)).

First of all, contract of the method:-

> > Specify a custom Spring MessageSource for resolving validation
> >     messages, instead of relying on
> >     JSR-303's default
> >     "ValidationMessages.properties" bundle
> >     in the classpath. This may refer to a
> >     Spring context's shared
> >     "messageSource" bean, or to some
> >     special MessageSource setup for
> >     validation purposes only.
>
> NOTE: This feature requires Hibernate
>   Validator 4.1 or higher on the
>   classpath. You may nevertheless use a
>   different validation provider but
>   Hibernate Validator's
>   ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator
>   class must be accessible during
>   configuration.
>
> Specify either this property or
>   "messageInterpolator", not both. If
>   you would like to build a custom
>   MessageInterpolator, consider deriving
>   from Hibernate Validator's
>   ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator and
>   passing in a Spring
>   MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator
>   when constructing your interpolator.

You can specify your custom message.properties(or .xml) by invoking this method... like this...

**my-beans.xml**

```
<bean name="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="resourceBundleLocator"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="resourceBundleLocator" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>META-INF/validation_errors</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**validation_errors.properties**

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=MyNotNullMessage
```

**Person.java**

```
    class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**BeanValidationTest.java**

```
    public class BeanValidationTest {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext; 

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() {
        applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/webmvc-beans.xml");
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = applicationContext.getBean("validator", LocalValidatorFactoryBean.class);
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setLastName("dude");
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(person);
        for(ConstraintViolation<Person> violation : violations) {
            System.out.println("Custom Message:- " + violation.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**Outupt:** `Custom Message:- MyNotNullMessage`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution if you want to mix the existing hibernate validation messages and custom validation messages :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="i18n,iso-i18n,org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages" />
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
</bean>
```

(see [Web MVC framework Validation section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-validation) and [Configuring a Bean Validation Provider](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring) in Spring documentation)

Comment: where to use validator bean in annotation based configuration (Full Java configuration without XML).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Lu55, based on your answer I solved my problem!!

I just converted to a Configuration class, and I am posting here just in case anyone else need:

Import detail: it worked for me with ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, but it did not work using ResourceBundleMessageSource. I am not sure why.

```
@Configuration
public class ErrorConfig {

    @Bean
    public Validator validatorFactory (MessageSource messageSource) {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator =  new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return validator;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bean = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        bean.addBasenames("classpath:org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages","classpath:message");
        bean.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Inside my resource folder I have message.properties file.