# Include field name inside error message using Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I'm using Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final and I'm looking for the simplest way to include class field name in my error message.

What I found is the following thread [Using a custom ResourceBundle with Hibernate Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258314/using-a-custom-resourcebundle-with-hibernate-validator). According to this I should create my custom annotation for each constraint annotation adding one property to each one.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

The following code:

```
@Size(max = 5)
private String myField;
```

produces default error: *size must be between 0 and 5.*

I would like it to be: *myField size must be between 0 and 5.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who are looking for a way to access class inside your validator. Putting hibernate annotating on a class level instead of variable level gives you access to a class object (assuming that you have defined a custom validator).

```
public class myCustomValidator implements ContraintValidator <MyAnnotation, MyAnnotatedClass> {

    public void initialize (...){ ... };

    public boolean isValid (MyAnnotatedClass myAnnotatedClass) {

        // access to elements of your myAnnotatedClass

    }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

You can get the name of the field with the `getPropertyPath()` method from the [`ConstraintViolation` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html#getPropertyPath%28%29).

A good default error message can be:

```
violation.getPropertyPath() + " " + violation.getMessage();
```

Which will give you "foo may not be null", or "foo.bar may not be null" in the case of nested objects.

Answer (score 7):

If your messages are in `.properties` file then there is no interpolation variable for accessing property name but one way you can achieve that is

```
//in ValidationMessages.properties
app.validation.size.msg=size must be between {min} and {max}

@Size(min=10, max=15, message = "myField {app.validation.size.msg})
private String myField;
```

OR

```
//in ValidationMessages.properties
app.validation.size.msg=size must be between {min} and {max} but provided ${validatedValue}

@Size(min=10, max=15, message = "myField {app.validation.size.msg})
private String myField;
```

Reference: [message interpolation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#section-interpolation-with-message-expressions)

Comment: A better way so that internationalization is supported.
//in ValidationMessages.properties
app.FieldName=MyField
app.validation.size.msg=size must be between {min} and {max} but provided ${validatedValue}

@Size(min=10, max=15, message = "{app.FieldName}"+" "+ "{app.validation.size.msg}")
private String myField;

Answer (score 4):

I put every field validation message into the properties file, like this:

```
field.student.name.size.message = Student name size is not valid.
```

and in the bean, use it like this:

```
@Size(max = 5, message = "${field.student.name.size.message}")  
private String myField;
```

I know it isn't a perfect solution, but I also don't find a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any generic way but you can define custom error message and include field name in it.

```
@Size(max = 5, message = "myField size must be between 0 and 5")  
private String myField;
```

Comment: No internationalization that way.

Answer (score 1):

If validating a REST call in a controller and using a controller advice, you can combine field and default message from MethodArgumentNotValidException like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String errorMessage = exception
                .getBindingResult()
                .getFieldErrors()
                .stream()
                .map(fieldError -> fieldError.getField() + " " + fieldError.getDefaultMessage())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));


        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way so that internationalization is supported.

//in ValidationMessages.properties

app.FieldName=MyField

app.validation.size.msg=size must be between {min} and {max} but provided ${validatedValue}

@Size(min=10, max=15, message = "{app.FieldName}"+" "+ "{app.validation.size.msg}")
private String myField;

Answer (score 0):

use [oval](http://oval.sourceforge.net/) this has good number of annotations and possible ways to display messages.

Answer (score 0):

use this method(ex is ConstraintViolationException instance):

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> set =  ex.getConstraintViolations();
List<ErrorField> errorFields = new ArrayList<>(set.size());
ErrorField field = null;
for (Iterator<ConstraintViolation<?>> iterator = set.iterator();iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    ConstraintViolation<?> next =  iterator.next();
   System.out.println(((PathImpl)next.getPropertyPath())
            .getLeafNode().getName() + "  " +next.getMessage());


}
```