# Changing Property file name for Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I don't want to use ValidationMessages.properties to hold the messages for my app.  I want to use what everything else uses:  LabelNames.properties.

Any way that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can use `ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator` and its bundle locator API. A custom bundle name can be specified like:

```
Validator validator = 
   Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
      .configure()
      .messageInterpolator(
         new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(
            new PlatformResourceBundleLocator( "LabelNames" )))
      .buildValidatorFactory()
      .getValidator();
```

Comment: Where do I put this? Can I put this in a startup class or am I misunderstanding something? I am using Spring MVC so I don't use the Validator object...

Answer (score 0):

When working with Spring, refer from `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` to a `MessageSource` for the required bundle as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258314/using-a-custom-resourcebundle-with-hibernate-validator).