# How to escape arguments when using hibernate validator with a custom messagesource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I've something like:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>...</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>
```

And some custom validator (has a `values` attribute) using this message:

```
validation.constraints.PossibleValues.message=The provided value "${validatedValue}" is invalid. Possible values: {values}
```

The issue is that the `{` and `}` are not there anymore in `AbstractMessageInterpolator#interpolateMessage`, so I don't get parameter interpolation.

I tried various escaping like `'{'validatedValue'}'`, `\\{` without success.

Does someone know how to escape the message arguments in such case?

(I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258314/using-a-custom-resourcebundle-with-hibernate-validator), but it doesn't help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using almost the same configuration you have:

```
  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="false" />
    <property name="basenames" value="classpath:applicationMessages,classpath:ValidationMessages"/>
  </bean>
```

And in my ValidationMessages.properties i overwrite some messages to Galician language using simple { and } for interpolated variables. For example:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Min.message=debe ser maior o igual a {value}
...
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length.message=debe ter unha lonxitude entre {min} e {max}
```

The only strange behaviour is that if you want to put single quote you need to escape it with a single quote:

```
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ScriptAssert.message=o script ''{script}'' non devolve true
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that (that's what's supposed to work according to the doc) without success, but maybe the issue is with `useCodeAsDefaultMessage` I will try that

Comment: Hum the issue is because of  `useCodeAsDefaultMessage `, I will declare another message source as a workaround for now. Thanks.