# Spring portlet mvc: @Valid does not seem to work

Tags: java, spring, validation, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I created a bean class and use it in my controller but it does not seem to work.
Namely even though I enter an invalid age, `result.hasErrors` is still false.

Bean class:

```
public class User{
    @Min(13)
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName(){
            return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Controller snippet:

```
@ActionMapping(params = "myAction=validateUser")
    public void validateUser(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result ){      

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            for(ObjectError oe : result.getAllErrors()){
                System.out.println(oe.getDefaultMessage());
            }
        } else{
            //code
        }
    }
```

JSP:

```
<form:form action="${registerUser}" method="post" commandName="user">
    <b>User</b> 
    <form:input path="age"/>
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="register"/>
</form:form>
```

---

edit:
My userRegistration-portlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        ">

    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <import resource="spring-hibernate.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="comjohndoe.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="comjohndoe.model" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="comjohndoe.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="comjohndoe.util" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="comjohndoecontroller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It's the mvc:spring-validation line that is giving me the: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.c the matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for the element mvc:annotation-driven.` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to enable jsr-303 validation. If you don't want to use it for some reason, or if at some point it starts creating problems (like it did for me), take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693397/howto-get-rid-of-mvcannotation-driven)

Update:
in `schemaLocation` the mvc entry should contain these *two*:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I tried placing it in my userRegistration-portlet.xml but I get an: the prefix mvc for mvc:annotation-driven is not defined. But when I google <mvc:annotation-driven /> I don't see any differences?

Comment: Edit: added: xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" and I also added: http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd to my schemalocation. And now I get the error: the matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for the element mvc:annotation-driven. Sorry for the double post but my internet is really slow. So I might also miss some responses.

Comment: I think I might be missing a maven dependencies, but I can't really think of one.

Comment: @Jack - post your bean definition xml file.

Comment: @Bohzo, sadly that didn't change anything.

Comment: I already get the error in my compiler (eclipse 3.6). Compiling and deploying it returns in the same message being delivered by a saxparseeception. So if I was only missing that missing line, I'm really thinking of a library problem. But I don't see any missing ones. And since I have quite a lot of dependencies also posting that will probably make the startpost too long.

Comment: @jack - you've put them in reverse order. the short one is above the xsd path.

Comment: Oh damn, never knew that one mattered... I feel really stupid now. Just wasted about an hour on that error.

Comment: Getting one more error (hopefully the last): g.springframework.beans.factory.Bea
nCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validatio
n.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed;
 nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLogger
Binder However I do have have slf4j dependency:<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Update: added the log4j12 dependency and now I get another error. Now it deploys, but when I visit the page I get an: Error creating bean wit
h name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#
0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.engine.Configuratio
nImpl in my console

Comment: @jack well, add Hibernate Validator to the classpath :) You need a JSR-303 provider

Comment: I have hibernate-validator 4.0.2.GA in my pom.xml. Which is why I'm so confused... Your e-mail is glamd@ etc right? I e-mailed you which might be easier than our slowchat.

Comment: sorry, I'm not answering SO stuff on email ;)

Comment: Feel free to put the answer here, but I think we could find the answer sooner if we e-mailed a little bit (if you wouldn't mind). I'm just getting a bit frazzled because on first sight it should work but I'm getting NullPointerExceptions etc due to it.

Comment: @jack - look, I think I answered the question as it is. Now the fact that other problems arise is perhaps material for other questions.

Comment: You certainly have, I just wanted to keep this going since it already has most of the information. I just started a second thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285393/spring-validation-portlet-issues-such-as-noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem. I read https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6817 and worked the problem around by adding to my config:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

<bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean id="configurableWebBindingInitializer" class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="validator">
                <ref bean="validator"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**You also need to have a JSR-303 validator in your project in order for it to be available** For this I used Hibernate Validator: http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html

Comment: I wish I found this post earlier. 99% of all the examples out there are missing this little bit of critical information.

Comment: for an unknown reason, that solution did not work for me, but @Andy's did !

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following, that is how I solved in the spring portlet mvc project.

1. Add `mvc:annotation-driven` to your applicatonContext.xml
2. Add the following code in your controller:

   `@Autowired
   private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;`

   `@InitBinder
   public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
       binder.setValidator(validator);
   }`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that `ServletRequestDataBinder` (extends DataBinder) has no `org.springframework.validation.Validator` instance, so it does not validate anything (to validate @Valid annotated bean you must have javax.validation.Validator instance).

**org.springframework.validation.DataBinder**

```
    public void validate() {
            Validator validator = getValidator();
            if (validator != null) {
                validator.validate(getTarget(), getBindingResult());
            }
        }
```

You can set the Validator instance in `@InitBinder` annotated methods:-

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new MyValidator());
    }
```

Yo can also set the validator instance in [WebBindingInitializer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder).

**StandardBindingInitializer**

```
   public class StandardBindingInitializer implements WebBindingInitializer {
        @Autowired
        private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;
        public void setValidatorFactory(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator) {
            this.validator = validator;
        }

        @Override
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
            binder.setValidator(validator);
    }
}
```

To create an instance of LocalValidatorFactoryBean either use [mvc:annotation-driven](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven) OR [set up LocalValidatorFactoryBean as bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186556/hibernate-validator-custom-resourcebundlelocator-and-spring).

Comment: That's quite a bit more verbose than the mvc:annotation-drive route but thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Use hibernate-validator jar 6.2 version and below and so it can support spring 5 and above versions...

Add dependency in pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```