# spring validation: (portlet) issues such as noclassdeffounderror

Tags: hibernate, spring, validation

I'm trying to get spring form validation working.
However I'm having some issues.

When I deploy my application I get:

```
Error creating bean wit
h name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#
0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethod
Error: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Ob
ject;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;


Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl
```

When I visit the page I get:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#
0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFo
undError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.engine.Configuratio
nImpl
```

Bean class:

```
public class User{
    @Min(13)
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName(){
            return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Controller snippet:

```
@ActionMapping(params = "myAction=validateUser")
    public void validateUser(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result ){      

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            for(ObjectError oe : result.getAllErrors()){
                System.out.println(oe.getDefaultMessage());
            }
        } else{
            //code
        }
    }
```

JSP:

```
<form:form action="${registerUser}" method="post" commandName="user">
    <b>User</b> 
    <form:input path="age"/>
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="register"/>
</form:form>
```

My userRegistration-portlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        ">

    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <import resource="spring-hibernate.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.johndoe.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.johndoe.model" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.johndoe.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.johndoe.util" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.johndoe.controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>       

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caused by: SPR-6817
So just added the tags myself.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dependency on `slf4j`. It's with an incorrect version. Hibernate defines a transitive dependency, so the correct version will be fetched.

Comment: Removing it still nets: org.springframework.beans.factory.Bea
nCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validatio
n.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed;
 nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageForma
tter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTu
ple;
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#

Comment: 0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethod
Error: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Ob
ject;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;

Comment: @jack - clean your target dir, and your tomcat. The old dependency is still there I guess. Also check if any other dependency is not including a wrong version of slf4j.

Comment: I checked a dependency hierarchy and the only thing referencing slf4j-api is the hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA which is referencing slf4j-api 1.5.6. I just scanned my liferay folder and the webapps\root\web-inf (root = name of the liferay application) and some other portlets for the portal.                              Like you suggested I did a mvn clean, undeployed my portlets, shut down my liferay and restarted it and yet the errors persist. noclassdeffounderror for localvalidatorfactorybean,

Comment: @jack - this is not the same error ;) it measn that spring-context.jar is not on the classpath now.

Comment: spring-context is in my pom (3th dependency listed)