# Use custom validation messages in Hibernate + Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-3, hibernate-validator

I tried the steps from the answer here: [Hibernate Validator, custom ResourceBundleLocator and Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186556/hibernate-validator-custom-resourcebundlelocator-and-spring)

But still just getting `{location.title.notEmpty}` as output instead of the message.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean name="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="resourceBundleLocator"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="resourceBundleLocator" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/validationMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

/WEB-INF/validationMessages.properties:

```
location.title.notEmpty=My custom message
```

Form (Class Location)

```
@NotEmpty( message = "{location.title.notEmpty}" )
private String title;
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: I do not know if this could cause that problem, but make sure that the message properties file has an empty line as last line.

Comment: nope that wasn't the problem, last empty line isn't needed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it! :-)

I added the following bean instead the above mentioned two into my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/validationMessages" />
  </bean>
```

Then, in my validationMessages.properties I used the following syntax:

```
NotEmpty.location.title=My custom Message
```

I guess this is the reason: I used the Hibernate validation annotations (not the javax ones)

And for general the syntax of the messages file should look like

```
[ConstraintName].[ClassName].[FieldName]=[Message]
```

Hope this helps some other people out there ;-)

And to access the message from a spring controller just add `@Autowired private MessageSource messageSource;` as a class field and use the `messageSource.getMessage` methods. Because I'm just using one locale I used `messageSource.getMessage( "NotEmpty.location.title", null, null )`

Comment: Nice, but it works also for Hibernate validation annotations :)

Comment: Yes, my first thought was it works only for hibernate validation annotations but it works for both - hibernate and javax.

Comment: It's not necessary to adjust the syntax when specifying the validator in  <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21508937/1672678 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/22655303/1672678.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, you can take advantage of autoconfiguration by adding the following key to application.properties: spring.messages.basename=your/basename/messages