# Spring MVC custom validation messages

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC project I created a model-class like this:

```
public class LoginModel {

    @NotBlank 
    private String username;

    // .. getter and setter...
}
```

After submitting a form, a controller method will be called. That method could look like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/submitLogin")
    public String submitLogin(@ModelAttribute("LM") @Valid LoginModel lm, BindingResult result) throws UnexpectedException {

        if(result.hasErrors()){
             return "Login";
        } else {
            // do something...
        }
}
```

Then - back on the jsp, I used the `<form:errors>` tag to display the error:

```
<form:errors path="username"/>
```

An error message will be displayed - that works fine. But I want to define a message resource which should overwrite the default message.

Maybe something like this

```
<form:errors path="username" resource="error.login"/>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You can read this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/9244317/2055854

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use custom validation messages in Hibernate + Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232284/use-custom-validation-messages-in-hibernate-spring)

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/) might help, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your message in the model class like this:

```
@NotBlank(message = "Please enter your username.")
private String username;
```

Comment: @CodeCannibal Will certainly do, but I'd rather go for i18n-messages and JSR-303 bean validation like in the comment by Orest, as this example here is hard to maintain in the long run.

Comment: you can add your messages in a property file.and configure the file in   the xml file.the property file is like this

 NotBlank.LoginModel .username= please enter your username

Comment: That's right of course. But again it's easier to leave that to the already build in mechanism. Look at how easy it is to define a custom message for `username` while still having a default custom message for `@NotBlank`.

Comment: ok. i use the above two methods for printing error messages.what is your expectation? tell me clearly.

Comment: I tried Orest's solution and it works- but only for the validation tag itself. So "NotBlank=This may not be blank" works, but "NotBlank.loginModel.username=This may also not be blank" does not. Instead the default message is shown. I tried the hole path ("NotBlank.my.package.loginModel.username") but it does not change anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @CodeCannibal Put `System.out.println("\n" + result.getFieldErrors() + "\n");` in your controller. You'll get a line containing an array `codes [NotBlank... ]`. Here you see what can be used as a key. (I'm usually good with `NotBlank.username = ...`)

Comment: @codecannibal. you can configure your property file in context.xml file.

Comment: @mybrainhurts . field error is not a form validation method

Comment: With "System.out.println("\n" + result.getFieldErrors() + "\n");" i found what resource key to use  - that helped me a lot. Thank you !