# Hibernate Custom Validator Messages Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to customize messages for Hibernate validation annotations (NOTNULL , NOTEMPTY ,...)  so that the application is able to read them from .proparties file.

I tried the solutions from the answer here:  [use custom validation in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186556/hibernate-validator-custom-resourcebundlelocator-and-spring)
[hibernate validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232284/use-custom-validation-messages-in-hibernate-spring)

but nothing works for me i still get the deafult messages (may not be null , may not be empty , ....).

Code sample :

application context.xml :

```
<bean name="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="resourceBundleLocator" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="resourceBundleLocator"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

user.java :

```
@NotNull
private String name;
```

messages.proparties :

```
user.name.notNull = incorrect name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the key name on your @NotNull annotation.

```
@NotNull(meassage="{user.name.notNull}")
private String name;
```

You can learn more from the link
https://teamtreehouse.com/library/displaying-validation-messages